# Swift how to use inline if else conditional statements with or (||) operator

Tags: swift

I have a simple block of code that I am trying to figure out how to add or operator in my if else statement

mode can be allEndPoints, none or direct.  I am hoping for the following: if mode is equal to allEndPoints or none then [] else anything it should be equal to [selection].

What I have tried below however I get issue: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bool'

```swift
let mode: String = "allEndPoints"
let selection:NSNumber = 501

try manager.add(
     toOut: mode == "allEndPoints" || "none" ? [] : [selection],
)
```

Comment: ```toOut = (mode == "allEndPoints" || mode == "") ? [] : [selection]```. It is bit unclear for me what u are trying to achieve. But u can add conditions like this  with inline statement

Comment: I just updated the question to refect what I was after I am looking for the way to do inline version like ````if mode == "allEndPoints" ||  "none" { //do something} else {//do something else}````

Comment: Off topic but maybe you should convert the possible values `mode` can have into an enum.

Comment: You still haven't put enough effort into this question. You're just cutting more out of it, but it's still gobbledegook to us. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just because you can doesn’t mean you should. This doesn’t make for very readable code. I like the enum idea.

Answer (score 2):

After the || just add mode == "none"

```
mode == "allEndPoints" || mode == "none" ? [] : [selection]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you think the `||` operator might do is not a thing it will do, and that's not particular to Swift.

[endpoint is a single word](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/endpoint).

```swift
enum Mode {
  case allEndpoints
  case direct
  case none
}

let mode = Mode.allEndpoints

[.allEndpoints, .none].contains(mode) ? [] : [selection]
```